# why React - component is loading before the img src path is fetched from server?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Here i am fetching data from a local server via axios via @reduxjs/toolkit.
The code below works fine.

```
function ProductDetails() {
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    let productsState = useSelector((state) => state.products);
    let prodId = useParams().id;
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProductDetails(prodId));
    }, [dispatch, prodId]);
    let { product, loading, error } = productsState;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="productDetails">
                <div className="productDetails__left">
                    <p>{product.name}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

redux store is working perfectly. Nothing wrong with it.

axiose response:-

```
{
    "success": true,
    "product": {
        "_id": "62d26e1c19177452c1db9d30",
        "user": "62cd4f2941c20f69eb61d163",
        "name": "HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop",
        "description": "Top perfomance gaming laptop",
        "price": 50000,
        "category": "gaming laptop",
        "ratings": 5,
        "images": [
            {
                "public_id": "placeholder",
                "url": "https://www.reliancedigital.in/medias/HP-15-ec2008AX-Laptops-491997441-i-1-1200Wx1200H-96Wx96H?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w4ODc1OHxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGltYWdlcy9oMzUvaDhkLzk2MjgyMDUxMjE1NjYuanBnfDY4NGUzYmViMTY3NzM1Mzk3ZmQ4OTA1ZmZlZDAxYmJkNWYwNzUwMTBmMTg3ZDdkNWM1NDJkYWY5MzMyMzExNDc",
                "_id": "62d26e1c19177452c1db9d31"
            }
        ],
        "stock": 19,
        "numOfReviews": 1,
        "reviews": [
            {
                "user": "62d2712709be7c1ae9363ee6",
                "name": "Brenden McCullam",
                "rating": 5,
                "comment": "cool stuff,again!!!",
                "_id": "62d2714b09be7c1ae9363eec"
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2022-07-16T07:51:56.757Z",
        "__v": 3
    }
}
```

...But when adding the below line of code in the div. Gives the following error.

```
<img src={product.images[0].url} alt="product" />
```

error:

```
ProductDetails.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at ProductDetails (ProductDetails.jsx:20:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Replacing the above line of code with the following line of code works fine again :

```
{product.images ? <img src={product.images[0].url} alt="product" /> : null}
```

--- or ---

```
{!loading ? <img src={product.images[0].url} alt="product" /> : null}
```

So it is obvious that when the component loads `img` the `src` `product.image` don't exist. But `product.name` and everything else exist for some reason.
why is this happening?
should i always wrap my whole component in if conditions ? is this the right way to go?
pls help?

Comment: You're not showing your `fetchProductDetails` code, so it's impossible for us to know if fetching images takes place separately from fetching other details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `product` is an empty object until the fetch completes, since it doesn't throw at `product.name`.

Outputting `product.name` doesn't throw an error because React silently treats the resulting `undefined` as no content. Trying to index `product.images` however will throw an error because you're trying to access a property on `undefined`.

And yes, you should wrap the output in a condition if it tries to access `null` or `undefined` otherwise. Or pass the value to a component that handles the empty value case internally.

```
<div>
  {product.images &&
    <img src={product.images[0].url} alt="product" />
  }
  <OptionalProductImage product={product} /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ternary expression to check the URL and if currently not there then use temp image till product image gets.

```js
<img src={product?.images?.[0]?.url || tempImage} alt="product" />
```

Comment: That's what OP is suggesting in their own post.

Comment: Thank you!.`product?.images?.[0]?.url` is very useful. I didn't even know such a syntax existed.